# How can I get returnValues from method getPastEvents?

Tags: events, logs

// This is where I get the event information.

```
const myEvent = myContract.getPastEvents('nftCreated', {fromBlock: 10230636})
```

// Then the log is something like this:

```
Promise {                                                                                                            
  <pending>,                                                                                                         
  [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 8614,                                                                                   
  [Symbol(trigger_async_id_symbol)]: 2656,                                                                           
  [Symbol(destroyed)]: { destroyed: false }                                                                          
}                                                                                                                    
> [                                                                                                                  
  {                                                                                                                  
    address: '0xF8C3b71BfE0bEEA2cF11F51C4B6370d96bD5c98d',                                                           
    blockHash: '0x239f98cab3616bd0e3218eed61a8c871c96d043f5594662364169680752e6b60',                                 
    blockNumber: 10230636,                                                                                           
    logIndex: 1,                                                                                                     
    removed: false,                                                                                                  
    transactionHash: '0x885a008946923b39b560d465614e119b668b5117e2acf47abe50d41cd286948f',                           
    transactionIndex: 0,                                                                                             
    id: 'log_185ce0cc',                                                                                              
    returnValues: Result {                                                                                           
      '0': 'xxxxxxxxxx',                                                             
      '1': '54366324124',                                                                                            
      '2': '0x3ac1b7722278da916f3996f09357ebdcb17ad8c54a9424b3826f8326c75a0582',                                     
      '3': '1645806587',                                                                                             
      owner: 'xxxxxxxxx',                                                           
      idToken: '54366324124',                                                                                        
      shaCode: '0x3ac1b7722278da916f3996f09357ebdcb17ad8c54a9424b3826f8326c75a0582',                                 
      timestamp: '1645806587'                                                                                        
    },                                                                                                               
    event: 'nftCreated',                                                                                             
    signature: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',                                 
    raw: {                                                                                                           
      data: '0x000000000000000000000000e3bca80f9dfdc7f72e0e648cdb83c790b20ee45100000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000ca87c459c3ac1b7722278da916f3996f09357ebdcb17ad8c54a9424b3826f8326c75a0582000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000621903fb',                                                                              
      topics: [Array]                                                                                                
    }                                                                                                                
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getPastEvents` returns promise, you must use like below

```js
try {
  const nftCreatedEvents = await myContract.getPastEvents('nftCreated', {fromBlock: 10230636});

console.log(nftCreatedEvents.map(_ev => _ev.returnValues))
}catch(e) {
   console.log(e)
}
```

Comment: I just tried it and it worked, thank you very much!!